# React is not dynamically loading images

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to dynamically load images in a map function but it won't return anything.

I can get it to load a single image if I import it at the top of the page and hardcode the src but I have tried every solution I can find to do it dynamically and none of them work.

Here is what the code looks like. I am passing props with the title of the PNGs but nothing will load.

```
  const Project = (props) => {
    const proj = props.proj
   
    return ( 
      <div >
        {proj.map(({title, id}) =>{
          return(
            <div>
              <div className="..." key={id}>
                <img 
                  src={require(`../Assets/${title}.png`).default} 
                  alt={`Image of ${title} hompage`}
                  className='object-cover' 
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }

  export default Project;
```

The app was set up with create react app. I tried setting up a library but it didn't load the images either.

Comment: Before the return, if you `console.log(proj);` what do you get?

Comment: Not that this is the cause of the issue but the `key` in the second inner div should be set on the parent div instead

Comment: 0: {title: 'Assassination',..., id: 1}
1: {title: 'MERN Book Search', ..., id: 2}
2: {title: 'Fridgician', ..., id: 3}
length: 3 I have left out some of the info just to condence it. There is another chid above this that is a div that renders text but that is working correctly but this section just shows the Icon of a page with the corner torn and the alt text.